# CPU usage is high when running a Karate feature file with 2400 test cases

Tags: karate

I have a Karate feature with 7 scenarios that makes a total of 2400 test cases.

A) When I run this feature file, after a few minutes, it quickly takes up the CPU usage (100%) and freezes my laptop (I'm on Windows 10 - Karate 1.4.1). From the console it complains about Java Heap Space. I tried to increase max memory in pom file but it didn't help.

B) So I decided to break the feature into 7 smaller features, each has 100 - 800 test cases tops. This time all 2400 test cases can run successfully. I notice when a feature has been finished, the CPU usage is down for a while, like a cooldown.

Just out of curiosity, what difference does it make between A and B approaches? Thanks in advance .

Comment: it completely depends on the feature file. please do consider submitting a way to replicate, I am pointing to an example of someone who did it and even contributed a fix, that's what open source is all about: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2530